# Xpath of a text containing Bold text

Tags: xpath

I am trying to click on the link whose site is www.qualtrapharma.com‎ by searching in google 
"qualtra" but there is problem in writing xpath as `<cite>` tag contains `<B>` tag inside it. How to do any any one suggest?

```
<div class="f kv" style="white-space:nowrap">
   <cite class="vurls">
       www.
        <b>qualtra</b>
       pharma.com/
   </cite>
<div>
```

Comment: 'Click on a link', as in "with the mouse"? What has Google to do with this? What has XPath to do with this? Please clarify by editing your question.

Comment: I am sorry, but this is complete nonsense. I suggest you to learn programming, and not only try to emulate it.

Answer (score 3):

You may overcome this by using the '.' in the XPath, which stands for the 'text in the current node'.

The XPath would look like the following:

```
//cite[.='www.qualtrapharma.com/']
```

Comment: I am able to use the '.' expression to overcome the \b tag: span_xpath = '//span[contains(., "Ready to download")]' # . stands for text in the current node regardless of in bold or not